# Переключение сцен меню, карта MLAPI

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть начальная сцена(Меню) есть сцена и карта(Где должен появляться игрок), мне нужно сделать так что бы она переключалась при старте-присоединении к серверу в HLAPI были offline и online сцены а тут нету(я не нашёл). MLAPI довольно новый и по нему "гайдов" русских нету(
p.s или использовать старый HLAPI?